# Elimination Ordering for the ring $k[x,y]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

> How to show that the only elimination ordering on the ring $k[x,y]$ is the lexicographic ordering? (Ene and Herzog, *Gröbner Bases in Commutative Algebra*, Problem 3.1.)

**Definition** (Elimination Order): A monomial ordering on $R = k[x_1,\dots, x_n,y_1,\dots,y_m]$ is an elimination ordering for $x_1,\dots, x_n$ if whenever $f \in R$ such that $LM(f)\in k[y_1,\dots, y_m]$, then $f\in k[y_1,\dots,y_m]$

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $t_1=x^ay^b$, and $t_2=x^cy^d$. Then $t_1>_{\text{elim}}t_2$ is equivalent to $a>c$ or $a=c$ and $t_1>_{\text{revlex}}t_2$; in the last case we get $b>d$.

In your present definition (which is equivalent to the one you previously used) we have $x^i>y^j$ for all $i\ge1$ and $j\ge0$. Now suppose that $t_1>_{\text{elim}}t_2$. If $a<c$ then $x^{c-a}>y^b$ and therefore $x^c>x^ay^b$. This gives $x^cy^d>x^ay^b$, a contradiction. Thus $a\ge c$. If $a=c$ then necessarily $b>d$ and we are done.

Comment: All our comments got deleted? I have a question. You mentioned the definitions are equivalent, but I only have 1 polynomial in mine. So where is the comparison?

Comment: I just mean in this new definition I have here, I talk about an elimination ordering for a polynomial $f$ and its leading monomial is a polynomai only in $y$, but in the one I had before, I had a comparison between **two** polynomial about their degrees $t_1, t_2$ (like your first sentence). I know you are correct, so I will give you points.

Comment: @jacobsmith I got it now. Well, with a polynomial or two the definitions are equivalent, and this is more or less proved in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1642066/121097) to another question of yours.

Comment: can you clarify on what the contradiction is in your last line?

Comment: I mean how did you get $x^cy^d>x^ay^b$.

Comment: @jacobsmith I don't know which step troubles you. Recall that a monomial order has the following property: $m_1>m_2\implies m_1n>m_2n$ for any monomial $n$. This leads to $m_1>m_2\text{ and }n_1>n_2\implies m_1n_1>m_2n_2$. Moreover, $m>1$ for any monomial $m\ne 1$. I've used these properties in the last step since $y^d>1$ and $x^c>x^ay^b$.

Comment: I know, but you had $x^c > x^a y^b$. So by this, doesn't it get to $x^c y^d > x^a y^{b+d} > x^a y^b$? (ah never mind, I answered my own question...)

Comment: It's also ok as you did, but I've simply multiplied the two inequalities: $y^d>1$ and $x^c>x^ay^b$

Comment: Trying to fill in the details in your answer...is basically what I have been doing.