# $>$ is an elimination ordering for $x_1,\dots,x_t \iff x_i >x_j^m$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

> Let $R = k[x_1,\dots,x_t,x_{t+1},\dots,x_n]$ and $>$ a monomial ordering on $R$. Then $>$ is an elimination ordering for $x_1,\dots,x_t \iff x_i >x_j^m$ for all $1\leq i \leq t, t+1 \leq j \leq n$ and all $m \geq 0$. (Ene and Herzog, *Gröbner Bases in Commutative Algebra*, Problem 3.2.)

Recall

**Definition** (Elimination Ordering): A monomial ordering on $R = k[x_1,\dots, x_n,y_1,\dots,y_m]$ is an elimination ordering for $x_1,\dots, x_n$ if whenever $f \in R$ such that $LM(f)\in k[y_1,\dots, y_m]$, then $f\in k[y_1,\dots,y_m]$.

So I thought using $LM(f) \in k[x_{t+1},\dots,x_n]$ I could get first inequality, but I don't know the $m$ variable. The backward direction is not obvious to me.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $>$ is an elimination ordering for $x_1,\dots,x_t \iff x_i >x_j^m$ for all $1\leq i \leq t,\ t+1 \leq j \leq n$ and all $m \geq 0$.

A monomial ordering on $R = k[x_1,\dots, x_n]$ is an elimination ordering for $x_1,\dots, x_t$ if whenever $f \in R$ such that $LM(f)\in k[x_{t+1},\dots, x_n]$, then $f\in k[x_{t+1},\dots, x_n]$.

"$\Rightarrow$" Suppose $x_i<x_j^m$. Then $f=x_i-x_j^m$ has $LM(f)\in k[x_{t+1},\dots, x_n]$, so $f\in k[x_{t+1},\dots, x_n]$, a contradiction.

"$\Leftarrow$" Let $f \in R$ such that $LM(f)\in k[x_{t+1},\dots, x_n]$. If $f$ has a monomial $\mu$ which contains a variable $x_i$ with $1\le i\le t$, then $\mu> LM(f)$, a contradiction. Let's show that last claim. In fact, we want to show that $x_i>x_{t+1}^{k_{t+1}}\cdots x_n^{k_n}$. But $x_i>x_{t+1}^{k_{t+1}+\cdots +k_n}>x_{t+1}^{k_{t+1}}\cdots x_n^{k_n}$. (Your textbook tacitly assumes that $x_1>\cdots>x_n$.)